# Помогите, пожалуйста, найти подлежащее в предложении

Tags: грамотная-речь, синтаксис, члены-предложения, подлежащее, основа

*И газеты, и телевидение, и радио — все средства массовой информации переполнены рекламой.*

Подлежащее "средства" или "средства массовой информации"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это подлежащее, выраженное устойчивым сочетанием терминологического характера. Его членить нельзя, так что "средства массовой информации" и будут подлежащим. Другие примеры: красная смородина, геометрическая фигура, глагольная форма.